# Confusing React Native syntax

Tags: react-native

How would "item" know that it has the data from the Data properties? I mean I passed in the data using the data properties of Flatlist component and it seems I can give any name to the keyExtractor property and it will know to get the data from the data property. Is there any explanation for this? Thanks a lot and in advance.

```
<Flatlist 
data={someData} 
keyExtractor={item => item.TitleID}/>
```

Comment: it’s not confusing but pretty simple. All you is telling flat list that give me my data item and I will tell you which key to use for the UI component. So your function accept a parameter, you can name it anything, which reference to your data item and your function is  responsible to return unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a briefly introduction and an example of what [callback functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) are and how to use them.

Basically you can define a function and it's parameters with any types. By that, you can also expect functions as parameters (those are also called [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)) and call them inside the parent function at any time you wish. Look at this and especially at the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

```js
function bar(something) {
  console.log(something);
}

function foo(callback) {
 callback("Hello");
}

// This will generate the output 'Hello'.
foo(bar);

// This is the same, but using lambda calculus.
foo(something => console.log(something));
```

As you can see, you can pass function definitions as parameters to other functions. This is exactly, what your example is doing. I also give you an extra example.

```js
import React from "react";

const FlatList = ({ keyExtractor, data, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{keyExtractor(item)}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default FlatList;
```

Here I tried to mockup the `FlatList` of your example. You can see the `data.map` call, which acts as the higher order function from the previous example. The `FlatList` component has a property called `keyExtractor`, which will be called for each element of the `data` property. Now, you can easily provide `keyExtractor` as follows.

```js
const someData = [
  { name: "Something", id: 1 },
  { name: "Anything", id: 2 }
];

//...

<FlatList
  data={someData}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

This will render an unordered list, which contains the `id` of every element of `someData`. In this case it is just a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) of your data.

Here the executable example https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-paper-lmi22.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `FlatList` passes your data item to the keyExtractor.

Here your function `myKeyExtractor` accepts a parameter, which is basically the reference to your data.

```
function myKeyExtractor(item) {
  return item.TitleID;
}

<Flatlist 
  data={someData} 
  keyExtractor={myKeyExtractor}
/>
```

Let's take a simple example here.
It is similar to the parameters of `add` and `subtract` functions here.

You could name the parameters anything you like. Parameters are just placeholders for your value.

```
function add(x, y) {
   return x + y;
}

function subtract(thisIsAFirstParameter, thisIsASecondParamater) {
   return thisIsAFirstParameter - thisIsASecondParamater;
}

add(10, 5);
subtract(10, 5);
```

Comment: I don't think he has any problem with the understanding of functions in general, but with the understanding of how callback functions work.